# How to map VIM to run current RSpec file in console?

Tags: vim

I'm trying this:

```
inoremap <F2> :!rspec %
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I hit F2 and nothing happens.

Comment: In what mode? (normal, insert… ?) In what environment? (terminal, GUI?) On what OS?

Comment: In normal mode, console VIM on Ubuntu 12

Comment: You think my script looks ok?

Comment: What do you want to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "i" in `inoremap` means "insert mode": your mapping is an insert mode mapping so it obviously won't work in normal mode.

Try `nnoremap` ("n" for "normal mode") instead and add `<CR>` at the end to actually execute the command:

```
inoremap <F2> :!rspec %<CR>
```

Since we are at it, you could also modify it to "write and run":

```
nnoremap <F2> :update<bar>!rspec %<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a better solution to check the file with `rspec` (put these lines in to your `.vimrc`, it needs `nocompatible` to be set, works in insert mode):

```
" Open quickfix window after :make if there was errors.
autocmd  QuickFixCmdPost  *  botright cwindow

inoremap  <F2>  :call Rspec()<CR>

" Check the file with rspec, don't forget to save it before calling.
function Rspec()

  let save_makeprg = &makeprg
  compiler rspec
  let &makeprg = 'rspec "' . expand( '%' ) . '"'
  echo expand( &makeprg )
  silent make
  let &makeprg = save_makeprg
  redraw!

endfunction
```

It will list the errors in quickfix window.